# How to optimize list of long running operations in C# (parallelism) (.NET 4.8)

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I have a long list of data that needs to be processed.

```
var dataList = getData(); // list of > 5000 items

foreach (var data in dataList)
{
    // this takes about 1.5 seconds
    await RunLongLastingFunction(data).ConfigureAwait(false); 
}
```

How should I optimize the code for run in a concurrent way?

Should I go the way of

- `Task.WhenAll`
- `Parallel.ForEach`
- `ThreadPool`

Comment: Are they IO bound - or CPU bound? If they're IO bound then there's no advantage to using parallelism.

Comment: @Dai Actually, I run two versions of this. One just updating a SQL server (on another machine) and one reading and copying file into the database. I guess that counts for Io bound ?

Comment: `If they're IO bound then there's no advantage to using parallelism` - why would that be the case? there are whole bunch of file copy / file explorer alternatives that claim to have better file transfer speed because they use multiple threads to copy - while windows only uses one thread? @Dai

Comment: @RandRandom For copying/moving lots of small (all under ~64KB) files, yes - there can be performance improvements by using multiple threads, but that's only a workaround for the lack of support for overlapped IO in Windows for meta-filesystem-operations (and often involves other bottlenecks too), whereas large/bulk data transfers (e.g. moving a multi-gigabyte file) is definitely disk-IO-bound and won't benefit at all from having multiple threads trying to squeeze through a door, _Three Stooges_-style.

Comment: BTW "**long** list" - 5000 items in context of a DB is not really _that_ much. So, is it safe to assume that _each item_ takes a long _time_ to be processed?

Comment: Since your operation is asynchronous, you should use `Task.WhenAll` or `Parallel.ForEachAsync`; do not use `Parallel.ForEach` or the thread pool.

Comment: @Fildor. Yes. At least 1.5 seconds each

Comment: @StephenCleary Do we have Parallell.ForEachAsync in .net framework 4.8 ?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEachAsync` was introduced with `.NET 6.0` but have a look at [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync/).

Comment: So, this is async DB-I/O and it takes a lot of time to process each item ... did you take the time and find out, _where_ most of that time is spent? My suspicion would be that you are trying to optimize the wrong abstraction. Maybe you can split the process, so you can introduce concurrency where it actually makes sense and bulk-operations where _that_ makes sense ... do I make sense?

Comment: ^^ Like if there is a specific portion in that process that is CPU-Bound, then you might want to separate that, fan out onto multiple Cores, do heavy calculations in parallel, then collect batches and write to DB in bulk?